# How can one add a key/value pair to an existing key/value pair?

Tags: javascript

I have to below code. I'm trying to create a grouped object thats groups by **phase** then by **block** using key value pairs.

Simplified item:

```
Item = {
Description: "Description of item",
Value: 199.99,
ValueComplete : 50,
Phase : "Phase 1",
Block : 1,
}
```

Code snippet:

```
var result = {};
Items.forEach(item => {
 //Phase
 var phase = item.Phase ?? 'None';
 if (!result[phase]) {
   result[phase] = [];
 }

 //Blocks
 var block = item.Block ?? 'None';
 if (!result[phase][block]) {
   result[phase][block] = []
 }

 result[phase][block].push(item);
});
```

Below is the results of the above code. Object is correct at the breakpoint but the phase's length is 0 so therefor all block information is thrown away.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide Items property?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `??=` operator to conditionally create missing phase objects and block arrays:

```js
const grouped = items.reduce((r, item) => (((r[item.Phase ?? 'None'] ??= {})[item.Block ?? 'None'] ??= []).push(item), r), {});
console.log(grouped);
```

```html
<script>
const items = [{
    Description: "Description of item",
    Value: 199.99,
    ValueComplete: 50,
    Phase: "Phase 1",
    Block: 1,
},
{
    Description: "Description of item",
    Value: 199.99,
    ValueComplete: 100,
    Phase: "Phase 1",
    Block: 1,
},
{
    Description: "Description of item",
    Value: 199.99,
    ValueComplete: 50,
    Block: 1,
},
{
    Description: "Description of item",
    Value: 199.99,
    ValueComplete: 50,
    Phase: "Phase 1",
},
{
    Description: "Description of item",
    Value: 199.99,
    ValueComplete: 50,
    Phase: "Phase 1",
    Block: 2,
},
{
    Description: "Description of item",
    Value: 199.99,
    ValueComplete: 50,
    Phase: "Phase 1",
    Block: 2,
},
{
    Description: "Description of item",
    Value: 199.99,
    ValueComplete: 50,
    Phase: "Phase 2",
    Block: 1,
},
{
    Description: "Description of item",
    Value: 199.99,
    ValueComplete: 50,
    Phase: "Phase 2",
}
];

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're facing is because you're initializing result[phase] as an array ([]), but then you're trying to use it as an object to store blocks.

To fix this, you should initialize result[phase] as an object ({}) instead of an array.

Here's the corrected code:

```
  const result = {};
Items.forEach(item => {
  // Phase
  const phase = item.Phase ?? 'None';
  if (!result[phase]) {
    result[phase] = {};  // Initialize as an object
  }

  // Blocks
  const block = item.Block ?? 'None';
  if (!result[phase][block]) {
    result[phase][block] = [];
  }

  result[phase][block].push(item);
});
```

With this change, the result object will have the structure:

```
{
  "Phase 1": {
    "1": [Item1, Item2, ...],
    "2": [Item3, Item4, ...],
    ...
  },
  "Phase 2": {
    "1": [Item5, Item6, ...],
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```